# Boost converter with regulator

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, power-supply

[image][image]

I have set up a boost converter with a regulator in LTspice, but I get a lower voltage at the output than at the input. What could be the reason?

Comment: Look at your compensator: 1mR along with 1000uF. Do you think that these values are normal?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is my problem, how can i dimension that?

Comment: when I change the values ​​my output voltage stays the same

Comment: What happens if you remove them?

Comment: Try running it 'manually' first. Put a fixed pulse waveform into the switch, and see what happens. Find out what the various parts do open loop before you close the loop and complicate things.

Comment: If I delete the capacitor and the resistor in my PI regulator, then I get 24 V at the output as desired, for this I also had to increase the resistance at the output to R1 = 10G. What I want to achieve: to simulate a boost converter with a constant output voltage, that's what I built this regulator for, but the knowledge from my lecture and university was not enough for me, I don't know how to properly simulate the values, I work with LTspice

Comment: I shared the new picture above again :)